# Can I use Javascript to detect and fix unclosed attribute tags?

Tags: javascript

Without wanting to give away too much context, I need some code which can detect and fix errors such as the below.

```
<p property"Not closed>Paragraph</p>
```

As you can see, the 'property' attribute is opened, but not closed. Is it possible to use **Javascript** to detect this problem, and fix it?

Performance hits are not an issue at this stage.

Comment: You can use HTML tidy to do this for you.. http://www.html-tidy.org/

Comment: You can check  [this](https://gist.github.com/Munawwar/9353965)

Comment: @Tushar: Tags aren't attributes.

Comment: I wrote an answer, then realised that it depended too much on context. So "Without wanting to give away too much context" you haven't provided *enough* context.

Comment: Yes, you can use JavaScript for almost anything. In this case, you *shouldn't*. Fix the issues at the source, not at the client.

Comment: Thanks @rajaprabhu-aravindasamy - I'll check that out

Comment: Thanks @user2181397 - I'll check that out

Comment: Javascript operates on the DOM, it doesn't have access to the original HTML source. By the time JS runs, the browser has already parsed the source, and it would be very difficult for JS to figure out where the syntax errors were.

Comment: Your attribute is also missing the `=` sign. So the browser will parse that as two separate attributes: `property` with no value, and then `Not closed ...` up to the next `"` that it finds.